# Unity mobile game that communicates with Google App Engine Backend

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints, unity-game-engine

I want to build a mobile game in `Unity` (for android, IOS , and the web) that uses and communicates with a server built with google app engine.Specifically I was wondering if I can use `Google cloud messages` and `Google cloud endpoints` directly in `Unity`.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?